# FactoryBot: create the same object multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In one of my RSpec test, I am creating multiple objects from the same factory definition

Eg

```
FactoryBot.create(:model_1)
FactoryBot.create(:model_1)
FactoryBot.create(:model_1)
```

Is there a method that `factory_bot` provides to do this in one line

I know that I can do

```
3.times {FactoryBot.create(:model_1)}
```

But I am looking for something that `factory_bot` provides for creating multiple objects of the same model.

[Note: FactoryBot was originally named FactoryGirl](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/factory_bot)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can create a list like this (hence create x objects at once):

```
FactoryBot.create_list(:model_1, 3)
```

Documentation [lives here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

[Note: FactoryBot was originally named FactoryGirl](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/factory_bot)

Comment: What if i want to create multiple objects like `FactoryGirl.create(:model_1, :type => "something")`?

Comment: look in the doc, you can pass params hash as third argument

Answer (score 15):

```
FactoryBot.create_list :factory_name, 2, attribute_name: 'value'
```

Simple and best way to move.

You can ignore the attribute names if not needed the same, and use sequence instead.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this has been updated since the answer was posted, but now you would do the following

```
FactoryBot.create_list(:model_1, 3)
```

see
[Getting Started](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#building-or-creating-multiple-records)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this for a model with validation, I was able to do the following in my test.

```
10.times do |i|
  create(
    :object,
    property: i
  )
end
```